# jQuery API: .ajaxStart() doesn't seem to work quite in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

anybody has idea why this code doesn't work quite well in Chrome browser:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    alert('ajax request sent');
  });
});
```

I tried this only on Chrome v.25. One of several ajax request on the page where this sample is taken from works well, but the rest of them don't want to respond. I work on Yii framework on PHP and it generates plenty of JavaScript code that I'm not much familiar with. Is it possible that some framework generated part or previously introduced from myself code to interfere with that sample above?

I tried also `.on('ajaxStart', myfunction)`, `.delegate('ajaxStart', myfunction)`, `.bind('ajaxStart', myfunction)`

Notice: The sample of code above is executed once the page is loaded. I send my ajax request with a click on a button. I do click the button once the page is loaded.

Notice 2: I include jQuery along with bootstrap JavaScript library.

Comment: When you have scripting problems, first of all open the developer console. That's where this code would print "syntax error".

Comment: @Jon I don't have syntax error, I wrongly edit this piece of code here. Now it's corrected. Please don't criticize me. Everybody makes mistakes, event the best.

Comment: Maybe you are not sending any ajax request...

Comment: @A. Wolff I'm sure I do. I see the request with the integrated developer tools and with trace log also ... and it gets successful response.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU: That was a suggestion aimed at improvement, not criticism.

Comment: I think the problem is you are sending ajax before event ajaxStart is bound. As we still don't know how you are doing your ajax request, we can just speculate...

Comment: The sample of code above is executed once the page is loaded. I send my ajax request with a click on a button. I do click it once the page is loaded. So your suggestion is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to put the sample after all JavaScript in my page. In case anyone has encounter similar issue and this solution still doesn't help, I advise him to put the following line in the beginning of body tag in his page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({'global':true});
```

and to read [this](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Comment: We really cannot help resolve this without a jsfiddle or similar.  You can fake ajax calls in it too : http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html
Perhaps anonymise your code if you're worried about exposing specific details on the net and I'm sure people will do their best to help.  I find it somewhat unlikely that it is a jQuery bug but you never know.

Comment: Anyway, the JavaScript's behavior I have now satisfies me. Thank you all guys :)

Answer (score 5):

You have one too many brackets in the code.
The below will work in chrome.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      alert('ajax request sent');    
  });
});
```

Comment: My original code is like yours I just did typo here in the site. And it still doesn't get trigger.

Comment: As I said, with the corrected code it will work in Chrome. Without more code we can't help you.  You realise that this is an event that only happens if an ajax request is actually sent by another function/piece of code?

Comment: I just noticed that one ajax requests in my code works like a charm. But I have a problem with the rest of them. Sorry the code is too big to post it here. It's a php + javascript project. I include several javascript files in a single page. The sample above is a piece of a code from the project.